# How did samurai keep their blade effective when away from any sharpening tools?

Tags: weapons, sword, samurai

I was wondering, regardless of the type of blade, how did samurais keep their blade effective when they are away from any sharpening tools / professionals.

Coming from daily using a Japanese chef knife, there is a significant difference between honing and sharpening. Honing is done very frequently, minutes intervals on intense usage, while sharpening under the same usage could be done in months intervals. Honing is also very cost efficient, with little skill and time the results are significant.

So I'm guessing, since honing is kind of simple (technique-wise) and very effective, while sharpening is quite an art, did samurais hone their blades frequently? If so how did they are away?

Comment: Should I rewrite it there or is there any technical way to move it ?

Comment: @Sardathrion Do you really think this is a better fit for history? I would expect this would be a better fit here.

Comment: @mattm We are martial arts expert, not historians. The samurai class is no more for more than a century, katana are no longer weapons of war used on far away battlefields, and even amongst those of us who still learn the ancient way of the sword, wood and bamboo is preferred over blunt steel let alone sharp steel.

Comment: Please migrate to history/.

Comment: `they are away from any sharpening tools / professionals` Since the sword is one of the tools of samurai trade, I would expect any samurai to know how to care for it while on campaign. Many cooks have no issues at all caring for their knives. And for major reparations any marching army would have a baggage train which would include artisans. In any case, while iconic, swords were **not** the main samurai weapon (https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10331/why-didnt-japanese-infantrymen-and-samurai-use-shields/10395#10395)

Comment: I know it's fiction, but George R. Martin gets some things right: Note how frequently we "catch up" to [Jorah Mormont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorah_Mormont) and see him honing his sword with a [whetstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whetstone). This would be a *twice daily and immediately after every combat* habit of every trained warrior prior to the modern age.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have the necessary tools needed to sharpen a sword. One would be a very tiny wetstone they could carry with them

Comment: Correct mentions of whetstones aside, "wartime" implies an *army* on the move. An army on the move would (among many other things) have *smiths* with them, forge, anvil and all, so both "sharpening tools" and "professionals" would probably be *easier* to come by than during peacetime when you might find yourself in a town that doesn't *have* a smithy...

Comment: In medieval Europe, that would be the squire's job. I am not familiar with Japanese history, but I suspect, that Samurai's were rich enough to have staff with them. People to tend to horses, cook meals, etc.

Comment: @DohnJoe: You have conflated knights and men-at-arms. A samurai is a man-at-arms, not a knight with knight's fief. He is the servant (ie retainer) responsible for the weapons expertise .

Comment: @Pieter thanks for the clarification, as I noted above I am not familiar with Japanese history. However, the Samurai might still have some other people along serving the tasks mentioned above. So, maybe a Samurai didn't have a squire of his own, but he could have other people along serving the same lord, which are subordinate to him?